# ADAL on Android Does Not Persist Tokens in Release Mode but Works Fine in Debug Mode

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms, adal

I have Xamarin.Forms (v2.2.0.31) targeting Android that uses ADAL 3.13.1 in Visual Studio 2015.

When I load the app using Debug configuration it works as expected. After signing on once the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) uses the Token Cache even if I close the app out completely and go back into it.

However, when I open the exact same project in Release mode it prompts me for credentials again.

When I attached Log Cat it shows the following when I access my Web API in DEBUG mode...
CacheType: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.Activedirectory.TokenCache (1 items)

Log Cat shows the following when I access my Web API in RELEASE mode...
CacheType: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.Activedirectory.TokenCache (0 items)
...then it prompts for credentials again.

This happens only after closing the app out completely otherwise it must keep it in memory. Do I have to enable special permissions in the Android Manifest for persistent token caching to work in Release mode?

EDIT: Ok, the problem has to do with Linking Behavior in the Android Project Properties > Android Options > Linker Tab. In release mode I was Linking SDK Assemblies Only to reduce space but apparently ADAL uses reflection and it's excluding some needed files. So I changed it to None and it work (but it bloated my app pretty good). Is there anyway to make this work and still link SDK Assemblies?

More information on linking behavior here...
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been issues with linking libs. Seems it's not fixed.

Try skip linking these:
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform;System.Runtime.Serialization;

**Especially, I think just skip System.Runtime.Serialization would work.**

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Thanks, that worked! For the Release configuration I went into the Android project properties > Android Options and on the Linker tab I entered System.Runtime.Serialization in the "Skip linking assemblies" text box.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with DataContractSerialization. When ADAL fails to write the cache blob, it simply swallows the exception.  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37491

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarity on this.